# How to deallocate Sprite Kit view

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a problem. It is happening that i cannot deallocate my Sprite Kit view totally. I have  set my view on nil and also dismiss the view controller. But when i start my game again, the stopwatch starts to run faster than is set to. And the next time even faster.

I have end my game like this:

```
 [skView presentScene:nil];
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

So everything works fine (game ends and view controller is dismissed), but there are problems when I am run my game for the second,third... (time).

Maybe is wrong that I am not stopping my update function that looks like this:

```
 - (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
```

Is there a way to stop  function like this one?

Comment: Perhaps your stopwatch code is the issue. I suggest you post that as well.

Comment: That's great but I didn't do anything...?!

Comment: You just reminded me about my stopwatch timer that i forgot to invalidate :)

Answer (score -1):

i am facing the same problem 
and i found the best solution is to load all texture of the current SKScene in Arrays 
and before you transfer to another SKScene [array removeAllObjects];

it works with me but do not dismiss the current SKScene

i hope this helps you